# Django Models - ForeignKey como chamar método dentro da class pelo Admin

Tags: python, django, model, chave-estrangeira, inline

Boa tarde Galera,

Minha situação é a seguinte. Eu tenho uma estrutura de class aninhadas para uma solução e estou empacado na seguinte situação: Eu tenho essas estrutura de class:

```py
class Atividade_estruturas_complementares(models.Model):
    atividades_complementares = models.OneToOneField(Atividade, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                                     related_name='atividades_complementares')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Estruturas Complementares'
        verbose_name = 'Estruturas Complementares'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.atividades_complementares.nome

class Estruturas_complementares(models.Model):
    passivo_id = models.ForeignKey(Passivo,
                                   related_name='complementares',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    atividade_complementar = models.ForeignKey(Atividade_estruturas_complementares, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                               related_name='atividade_estruturas_complementares')
    comprimento = models.DecimalField(
        'Comprimento', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    largura_altura = models.DecimalField(
        'Largura / Altura', max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    profundidade = models.DecimalField(
        'Profundidade', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    valor = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

A class Estruturas_complementares é registrada no admin como inline e atribuída a um outro model chamado Passivo. Ao salvar o passivo eu gostaria de atualizar o campo valor da class Estruturas_complementares com uma função que faz um calculo específico, eu já tenho a função porém não sei como relacionar para que no momento que eu salve o objeto passivo eu chame a função que inclui o valor no objeto estruturas_complementares. Eu pensei na possibilidade de chamar uma função em default, porém não obtive sucesso.

Gostaria de uma ajuda para melhorar essa implementação pois ainda sou novato em django e python. 
Caso precisem de mais informações estou a disposição.

models.py
Todas as classes estão no mesmo models.py, é um arquivo enorme, mas creio que a mais importante nesse caso seria a class passivo, que é o core do sistema, e está representada abaixo. edit* "TODAS AS CLASSES ABAIXO"

```py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from djgeojson.fields import PointField
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import SpatialReference, CoordTransform
from bdg import models as bdg_models
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
import django_tables2 as tables
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
from rest_framework import serializers
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedManyToManyField
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render
from .thumbs import ImageWithThumbsField
from sorl_thumbnail_serializer.fields import HyperlinkedSorlImageField
from drf_dynamic_fields import DynamicFieldsMixin
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
import zipfile
from sicro.models import Sicro


class Unidade(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=20)
    sigla = models.CharField('Sigla', max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sigla)


class Atividade(models.Model):
    codigoSICRO = models.OneToOneField(Sicro, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=200, unique=True)
    descricao = models.TextField('Descrição', max_length=300, blank=True)
    unidadeMedida = models.ForeignKey(Unidade, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class Reparo(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100, blank=True)
    descricao = models.TextField('Descrição', max_length=300, blank=True)
    atividades = models.ManyToManyField(Atividade)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


class Causa(models.Model):
    # feicao = models.ManyToManyField(Feicao)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Causas"


class Consequencia(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    valoracao = models.FloatField('Valoração', default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Consequências"
        verbose_name = "Consequência"


class Feicao(models.Model):
    # Opcoes Tipo
    erosao_uniforme = 'Erosão Uniforme'
    erosao_concentrada = 'Erosão Concentrada'
    escorregamento_rotacional = 'Escorregamento Rotacional'
    escorregamento_planar = 'Escorregamento Planar'
    queda_blocos_tombamento = 'Queda de blocos/tombamento'
    corrida = 'Corrida'
    rastejo = 'Rastejo'
    adensamento = 'Adensamento'

    tipos_opcoes = (
        (erosao_uniforme, "Erosão Uniforme"),
        (erosao_concentrada, "Erosão Concentrada"),
        (escorregamento_rotacional, "Escorregamento Rotacional"),
        (escorregamento_planar, "Escorregamento Planar"),
        (queda_blocos_tombamento, "Queda de blocos / tombamento"),
        (corrida, "Corrida"),
        (rastejo, "Rastejo"),
        (adensamento, "Adensamento")
    )
    nome = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=tipos_opcoes, blank=True, null=True)
    causas = models.ManyToManyField(Causa)
    consequencias = models.ManyToManyField(Consequencia)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Feições"


def calculoReparo(dimensao_comprimento, largura_faixa_dominio_total, dimensao_profundidade, metodos_reparo,
                  siglaEstado):
    comprimento = dimensao_comprimento
    altura_largura = largura_faixa_dominio_total
    profundidade = dimensao_profundidade
    estado = siglaEstado.lower()
    soma = 0.0
    for atividade in metodos_reparo.atividades.all():
        if atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'm':
            valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
            valor = list(valores[0].values())
            soma += valor[0] * float(comprimento)
        elif atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'tkm':
            valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
            valor = list(valores[0].values())
            pass
        elif atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'un':
            valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
            valor = list(valores[0].values())
            soma += valor[0]
        elif atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'm²':
            valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
            valor = list(valores[0].values())
            soma += valor[0] * float((comprimento * altura_largura))
        elif atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'm³':
            valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
            valor = list(valores[0].values())
            soma += valor[0] * float((comprimento * altura_largura * profundidade))
    return soma


valor_protecao_superficial = 0.0
valor_estruturas_complementares = 0.0


def calculoComplementares(atividade, comprimento, largura_altura, profundidade, passivo):
    estado = passivo.siglaEstado.lower()
    soma = 0.0
    if atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'm':
        valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
        valor = list(valores[0].values())
        soma += valor[0] * float(comprimento)
    elif atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'tkm':
        valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
        valor = list(valores[0].values())
        pass
    elif atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'un':
        valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
        valor = list(valores[0].values())
        soma += valor[0]
    elif atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'm²':
        valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
        valor = list(valores[0].values())
        soma += valor[0] * float((comprimento * largura_altura))
    elif atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'm³':
        valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
        valor = list(valores[0].values())
        soma += valor[0] * float((comprimento * largura_altura * profundidade))
    elif atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 't':
        valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
        valor = list(valores[0].values())
        soma += valor[0] * float((comprimento))
    return soma


def calculoSuperficial(atividade, comprimento, largura_altura, profundidade, passivo):
    estado = passivo.siglaEstado.lower()
    soma = 0.0
    if atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'm':
        valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
        valor = list(valores[0].values())
        soma += valor[0] * float(comprimento)
    elif atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'un':
        valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
        valor = list(valores[0].values())
        soma += valor[0]
    elif atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'm²':
        valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
        valor = list(valores[0].values())
        soma += valor[0] * float((comprimento * largura_altura))
    elif atividade.unidadeMedida.sigla == 'm³':
        valores = Sicro.objects.all().filter(codigo=str(atividade.codigoSICRO)).values(estado)
        valor = list(valores[0].values())
        soma += valor[0] * float((comprimento * largura_altura * profundidade))
    return soma


class Abrangencia(models.Model):
    atributo = models.CharField('Atributo', blank=True,
                                null=True, max_length=20)
    valoracao = models.FloatField('Valoração', default=1.0)

    descricao = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Abrangências'
        verbose_name = 'Abrangência'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.atributo


class Magnitude(models.Model):
    atributo = models.CharField('Atributo', blank=True,
                                null=True, max_length=20)
    valoracao = models.FloatField('Valoração', default=1.0)

    erosao = models.TextField('Erosão', )
    movimento_massa = models.TextField('Movimentos de massa', )
    adensamento = models.TextField('Adensamento', )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Magnitudes'
        verbose_name = 'Magnitude'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.atributo


class Interferencia(models.Model):
    descricao = models.CharField('Descrição', blank=True,
                                 null=True, max_length=100)
    valoracao = models.FloatField('Valoração', default=1.0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Interferências'
        verbose_name = 'Interferência'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descricao


def calculaGrandeza(abrangencia, magnitude):
    grandeza = (abrangencia.valoracao + magnitude.valoracao) / 2
    return grandeza


def calculaRisco(risco_ao_usuario, provaveis_consequencias):
    risco = 0.0
    consequencias = provaveis_consequencias.all()
    for consequencia in consequencias:
        risco += consequencia.valoracao
    risco = risco * risco_ao_usuario
    return risco

def calculaIndicePrioridade(self):
    g = calculaGrandeza(self.abrangencia, self.magnitude)
    # teste = self.provaveis_consequencias.all()
    r = calculaRisco(self.risco_ao_usuario, self.provaveis_consequencias)
    it = self.interferencia.valoracao
    ip = (0.55 * r) + (0.1 * g) + (0.1 * it)
    return ip
class Passivo(models.Model):
    # Opcoes relevo
    plano = 'PL'
    ondulado = 'ON'
    montanhoso = 'MO'

    relevo_opcoes = (
        (plano, 'Plano'),
        (ondulado, 'Ondulado'),
        (montanhoso, 'Montanhoso')
    )

    # Opcoes terceira_faixa_localizacao
    lado_direito = 'LD'
    lado_esquerdo = 'LE'
    inexistente = 'IN'
    ambos = 'AM'

    terceira_faixa_localizacao_opcoes = (
        (lado_direito, 'Lado Direito'),
        (lado_esquerdo, 'Lado Esquerdo'),
        (inexistente, 'Inexistente')
    )

    # opcoes pavimento
    pavimento_asfautico = 'PA'
    pavimento_concreto = 'PC'
    nao_pavimentado = 'NP'
    outro_pavimento = 'OP'
    pista_rolamento_pavimento_opcoes = (
        (pavimento_asfautico, 'Pavimento Asfaltico'),
        (pavimento_concreto, 'Pavimento Concreto'),
        (nao_pavimentado, 'Nao Pavimentado'),
        (outro_pavimento, 'Outro Pavimento')
    )

    # opcoes lado
    direito = 'D'
    esquerdo = 'E'
    indefinido = 'I'
    ambos = 'A'

    lado_opcoes = (
        (direito, 'Direito'),
        (esquerdo, 'Esquerdo'),
        (indefinido, 'Indefinido'),
        (ambos, 'Lado Direito e Esquerdo')
    )

    # Opcoes Perigo e sua valoração
    sem_perigo = 0.0
    perigo_potencial = 0.5
    perigo_iminente = 1.0
    perigo_instalado = 1.5

    nivel_gravidade_escolhas = (
        (sem_perigo, 'Sem Perigo'),
        (perigo_potencial, 'Perigo Potencial'),
        (perigo_iminente, 'Perigo Iminente'),
        (perigo_instalado, 'Perigo Instalado')
    )

    # MODELO
    data_inspecao = models.DateField('Data de inspeção', auto_now=False)

    # LOCALIZAÇÃO
    latitude = models.DecimalField(
        'Latitude', max_digits=14, decimal_places=10, blank=False, null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(
        'Longitude', max_digits=14, decimal_places=10, blank=False, null=True)
    km_ponto = models.DecimalField(
        'Km', blank=True, null=True, max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    lado = models.CharField('Lado de Ocorrência', blank=True,
                            null=True, max_length=1, choices=lado_opcoes)
    distancia_ao_eixo = models.CharField(
        'Distância do Passivo ao Eixo', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    area_ocorrencia_faixa_dominio = models.NullBooleanField(
        blank=True, null=True, default=False)
    area_ocorrencia_area_adjacente = models.NullBooleanField(
        blank=True, null=True, default=False)

    # CARACTERIZAÇÃO DO SEGMENTO RODOVIÁRIO
    largura_faixa_dominio_esquerda = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    largura_faixa_dominio_direita = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    pista_rolamento_numero = models.IntegerField(
        'nº de pistas de rolamento', blank=True, null=True)
    pista_rolamento_pavimento = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                                 choices=pista_rolamento_pavimento_opcoes,
                                                 default=pavimento_asfautico)
    acostamento_presenca = models.NullBooleanField(
        'Acostamento', default=False)
    terceira_faixa_localizacao = models.CharField('Terceira Faixa / Localização', max_length=50,
                                                  choices=terceira_faixa_localizacao_opcoes,
                                                  default=inexistente)
    relevo = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                              choices=relevo_opcoes,
                              default=plano)

    # CARACTERIZAÇÃO DO PASSIVO
    feicao = models.ForeignKey(Feicao, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    risco_ao_usuario = models.FloatField(choices=nivel_gravidade_escolhas, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    risco_ao_patrimonio = models.FloatField(choices=nivel_gravidade_escolhas, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    risco_ao_ambiente = models.FloatField(choices=nivel_gravidade_escolhas, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    possiveis_causas = ChainedManyToManyField(
        Causa,
        horizontal=True,
        verbose_name='Possiveis Causas',
        chained_field="feicao",
        chained_model_field="feicao",
    )
    provaveis_consequencias = ChainedManyToManyField(
        Consequencia,
        horizontal=True,
        verbose_name='Provaveis Consequências',
        chained_field="feicao",
        chained_model_field="feicao",
    )
    abrangencia = models.ForeignKey(Abrangencia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    magnitude = models.ForeignKey(Magnitude, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    interferencia = models.ForeignKey(Interferencia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    localizacao = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)
    modelo_3d = models.FileField(upload_to='models/', blank=True, null=True,
                                 validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['zip'])])
    modelo_3d_path = models.CharField(
        'Endereço do arquivo 3d (cloud.js)', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    croqui = models.ImageField('Croqui', blank=True, null=True)
    observacoes = models.TextField('Observações', blank=True, null=True)
    segmento_rodoviario = models.ForeignKey(
        bdg_models.Rodovia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, unique=False,
        verbose_name='Segmento Rodoviário')
    estado = models.CharField('Estado', blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    siglaEstado = models.CharField('Sigla', blank=True, null=True, max_length=2)
    municipio = models.CharField(
        'Município', blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)

    # MÉTODOS DE REPARO
    metodos_reparo = models.ForeignKey(Reparo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    dimensao_comprimento = models.DecimalField(
        'Comprimento', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    largura_faixa_dominio_total = models.DecimalField(
        'Largura / Altura', max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    dimensao_profundidade = models.DecimalField(
        'Profundidade', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    valor_total_reparo = models.FloatField('valor reparo', default=0.0)
    indice_prioridade = models.FloatField('Indice de Prioridade', default=0.0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if ((self.latitude != None) & (self.longitude != None)):
            coordinate = 'POINT(' + str(self.longitude) + \
                         ' ' + str(self.latitude) + ')'
            try:
                RODOVIA_FROM_LOCALIZACAO_ID = bdg_models.Rodovia.objects.filter(
                    geom__distance_lt=(GEOSGeometry(coordinate), D(m=5000)))[0]
                self.segmento_rodoviario = RODOVIA_FROM_LOCALIZACAO_ID
            except RuntimeError:
                print('Something wrong with input points')

                raise
            try:
                ESTADO_FROM_LOCALIZACAO_ID = bdg_models.Estado.objects.filter(
                    geom__intersects=(GEOSGeometry(coordinate)))
                self.estado = ESTADO_FROM_LOCALIZACAO_ID[0].nome
                self.siglaEstado = ESTADO_FROM_LOCALIZACAO_ID[0].sigla
                self.valor_total_reparo = calculoReparo(self.dimensao_comprimento, self.largura_faixa_dominio_total,
                                                        self.dimensao_profundidade, self.metodos_reparo,
                                                        self.siglaEstado)
                self.indice_prioridade = calculaIndicePrioridade(self)
                protecao_superficial = Protecao_superficial.objects.all()
                protecao_superficial
                for atividade in protecao_superficial:
                    print(atividade)


            except RuntimeError:
                print('Something wrong with input points')

                raise
            try:
                MUNICIPIO_FROM_LOCALIZACAO_ID = bdg_models.Municipio.objects.filter(
                    geom__intersects=(GEOSGeometry(coordinate)))
                self.municipio = MUNICIPIO_FROM_LOCALIZACAO_ID[0].nome
            except RuntimeError:
                print('Something wrong with input points')
                raise
            self.localizacao = GEOSGeometry(coordinate)
            if self.modelo_3d:
                try:
                    targetdir = 'static/models'
                    targetname = '/' + str(self.id)
                    self.modelo_3d_path = '/models' + targetname + '/cloud.js'
                    with zipfile.ZipFile(self.modelo_3d, "r") as zip_ref:
                        zip_ref.extractall(targetdir + targetname)
                except RuntimeError:
                    print('Something wrong with the unziping')
                    raise
            else:
                pass
        else:
            print('Preencher coordenadas')

        super(Passivo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Passivos"

    # def all_images(self):
    #     # code to determine which image to show. The First in this case.
    #     return self.fotos

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


# PROTEÇÃO SUPERFICIAL
class Atividade_protecao_superficial(models.Model):
    atividade_superficial = models.ForeignKey(Atividade, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                                related_name='atividade_superficial', primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Atividades Superficiais'
        verbose_name = 'Atividade Superficial'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.atividade_superficial.nome


class Protecao_superficial(models.Model):
    passivo_id = models.ForeignKey(Passivo,
                                   related_name='superficial',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    atividade_superficial = models.ForeignKey(Atividade_protecao_superficial, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                              related_name='atividade_protecao_superficial')
    comprimento = models.DecimalField(
        'Comprimento', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    largura_altura = models.DecimalField(
        'Largura / Altura', max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    profundidade = models.DecimalField(
        'Profundidade', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    valor = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Proteções Superficiais'
        verbose_name = 'Proteção Superficial'
        unique_together = (('passivo_id', 'atividade_superficial'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return ''


# ESTRUTURAS COMPLEMENTARES

class Atividade_estruturas_complementares(models.Model):
    atividade_complementar = models.ForeignKey(Atividade, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                                     related_name='atividade_complementar', primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Atividades Complementares'
        verbose_name = 'Atividade Complementar'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.atividade_complementar.nome


class Estruturas_complementares(models.Model):
    passivo_id = models.ForeignKey(Passivo,
                                   related_name='complementares',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    atividade_complementar = models.ForeignKey(Atividade_estruturas_complementares, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                               related_name='atividade_estruturas_complementares')
    comprimento = models.DecimalField(
        'Comprimento', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    largura_altura = models.DecimalField(
        'Largura / Altura', max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    profundidade = models.DecimalField(
        'Profundidade', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    valor = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Estrutura Complementar'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Estruturas Complementares'
        unique_together = (('passivo_id', 'atividade_complementar'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return ''


class Foto(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Passivo,
                                 related_name='fotos',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  # , default='no-img.png')
    image = ImageWithThumbsField(sizes=((100, 130), (200, 260)))
    descricao = models.CharField(
        'Descrição', max_length=300, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Fotos"

        def __str__(self):
            return ("Fotos do passivo"
```

admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.apps import apps
from .models import Feicao, Passivo, Causa, Consequencia, Foto, Local, Unidade, Atividade, Reparo, \
    Estruturas_complementares, Protecao_superficial, Atividade_estruturas_complementares, \
    Atividade_protecao_superficial, Abrangencia, Magnitude, Interferencia
from sorl.thumbnail.admin import AdminImageMixin
import nested_admin
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin
from jet.admin import CompactInline


class ReparoInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = Reparo
    extra = 0


class FotoInline(AdminImageMixin, nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = Foto
    extra = 0


class LocalInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = Local
    extra = 0


class Estruturas_complementares_inline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = Estruturas_complementares
    readonly_fields = ('valor',)
    extra = 0

class Protecao_superficial_inline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline):
    model = Protecao_superficial
    readonly_fields =('valor',)
    extra = 0

class PassivoAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin, LeafletGeoAdmin):
    model = Passivo
    list_filter = ['data_inspecao']
    autocomplete_fields = ['metodos_reparo', 'possiveis_causas', 'provaveis_consequencias',]
    list_display = ('id', 'segmento_rodoviario', 'km_ponto',
                    'lado', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'estado')
    readonly_fields = ('segmento_rodoviario', 'indice_prioridade', 'estado',
                       'municipio', 'modelo_3d_path','valor_total_reparo')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('data_inspecao',)
        }),
        ('Localização', {
            'fields': ('latitude', 'longitude', 'km_ponto', 'lado', 'distancia_ao_eixo', 'area_ocorrencia_faixa_dominio', 'area_ocorrencia_area_adjacente')
        }),
        ('Mapa', {
            'fields': ('localizacao',)
        }),
        ('Segmento Rodoviário', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('largura_faixa_dominio_esquerda', 'largura_faixa_dominio_direita', 'pista_rolamento_numero', 'pista_rolamento_pavimento', 'acostamento_presenca', 'terceira_faixa_localizacao', 'relevo')
        }),
        ('Caracterização', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('feicao', 'risco_ao_usuario', 'risco_ao_patrimonio', 'risco_ao_ambiente', 'possiveis_causas', 'provaveis_consequencias', 'abrangencia', 'magnitude', 'interferencia','indice_prioridade', 'modelo_3d', 'modelo_3d_path', 'croqui', 'observacoes', 'segmento_rodoviario', 'estado', 'municipio')
        }),
        ('Métodos de Reparo', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('metodos_reparo', 'dimensao_comprimento', 'largura_faixa_dominio_total', 'dimensao_profundidade', 'valor_total_reparo')
        }),
    )
    inlines = [Estruturas_complementares_inline, Protecao_superficial_inline, FotoInline, LocalInline]
```

Edit:

Eu comecei a testar ontem da seguinte maneira:

```py
def calcula_valor(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        atividade = Passivo.objects.update(id=kwargs['instance'])
        atividade.valor = calculoSuperficial(atividade.atividade_superficial,atividade.comprimento,atividade.largura_altura,atividade.profundidade, atividade.passivo_id)
    elif kwargs['update_fields']:
        atividade = Protecao_superficial.objects.create(passivo_id=kwargs['instance'])
        atividade.valor = calculoSuperficial(atividade.atividade_superficial,atividade.comprimento,atividade.largura_altura,atividade.profundidade, atividade.passivo_id)
    else:
        for atividade in Protecao_superficial.objects.all().filter(passivo_id_id=kwargs['instance']):
            valor = calculoSuperficial(atividade.atividade_superficial,atividade.comprimento,atividade.largura_altura,atividade.profundidade, atividade.passivo_id)
            atividade.valor = valor
            atividade.save() # Edit2: como descrito era apenas o .save() e a solução funcionou
post_save.connect(calcula_valor, sender=Passivo)
```

Quase deu certo, eu consigo ter acesso a todos os objetos que eu preciso, faço os calculos, porém na hora de salvar as alterações não estão sendo salvas, até onde eu pude ver, eu não estou sabendo anexar as informações ao contexto.

Comment: Olá viva dá uma vista de olhos [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348221/django-admin-tabularinline-modify-inline-item-attribute-before-save) tem um exemplo, se isso tornar muito complexo, partilha mais detalhes do teu models.py e o admin.py com o que já fizeste até agora. Uma outra sugestão, ou plano B seria criar um trigger, não recomendo a utilização de triggers em alguns casos provocam problemas de performance, se fôr uma tabela com poucos dados nesse caso em particular pode ser uma solução, i.e. ao gravares no Passivo o trigger é disparado e efetua a operação que queres.

Comment: Oi, melhorou. Mas podes colocar pf os objetos do models que estão no admin, assim é só copy e paste e tenho o teu cenário

Comment: vou fazer isso agora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conseguir o que precisava, não sei se foi a melhor solução, porém consegui alcançar da seguinte maneira.

```py
def calcula_valor(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        atividade = Passivo.objects.update(id=kwargs['instance'])
        atividade.valor = calculoSuperficial(atividade.atividade_superficial,atividade.comprimento,atividade.largura_altura,atividade.profundidade, atividade.passivo_id)
    elif kwargs['update_fields']:
        atividade = Protecao_superficial.objects.create(passivo_id=kwargs['instance'])
        atividade.valor = calculoSuperficial(atividade.atividade_superficial,atividade.comprimento,atividade.largura_altura,atividade.profundidade, atividade.passivo_id)
    else:
        for atividade in Protecao_superficial.objects.all().filter(passivo_id_id=kwargs['instance']):
            valor = calculoSuperficial(atividade.atividade_superficial,atividade.comprimento,atividade.largura_altura,atividade.profundidade, atividade.passivo_id)
            atividade.valor = valor
            atividade.save()
post_save.connect(calcula_valor, sender=Passivo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá viva percebi após a tua partilha que realmente já está bem grande a tua app e existe imensa coisa para instalar para te poder ajudar com um exemplo totalmente funcional. Quanto ao que tu queres, parte do que precisas já tens implementado, ou seja, o **save** no model Passivo. O que precisas é só adicionar uma linha de código, mas como definiste unique as 2 FK, e com imensas linhas de código, fico na dúvida se tens acesso ao atributo **atividade_complementar** no scope do objeto Passivo?

Na minha visão será esta uma possível solução, (um vez que não foi impossível testar o teu código), em que o passivo_id servido como id do próprio objeto, tudo bem e removes o segundo, senão terás de conseguir obter o ID da FK atividade_complementar para filtrar por esse também.

**Só com passivo_id**

```
Estruturas_complementares.objects.filter(passivo_id=self.id).update(largura_altura=12273)
```

**Com passivo_id e atividade_complementar**

```
Estruturas_complementares.objects.filter(passivo_id=self.id).filter(atividade_complementar=self.???).update(largura_altura=12273)
```

Comment: Ernesto, quando diz removes o segundo, fiquei confuso de qual trecho de código está se referindo, por acaso seria nesse?

passivo_id = models.ForeignKey(Passivo,
                                   related_name='superficial',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    atividade_superficial = models.ForeignKey(Atividade_protecao_superficial, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                              related_name='atividade_protecao_superficial')



Obrigado Ernesto, irei fazer os testes aqui e volto a dar feedback.

Comment: Não mexes no teu model, não utilizas o segundo "filter", ou seja o meu primeiro exemplo, para colocares no teu SAVE.